# Conversion between Eigen::Matrix4d and geometry_msgs::TransformStamped?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, eigen, tf2, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What would be the correct conversion from `Eigen::Matrix4d` to `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` or `geometry_msgs::Transform`, and from `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` or `geometry_msgs::Transform` to `Eigen::Matrix4d`?  Appreciate any help:-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365864/conversion-between-eigen::matrix4d-and-geometry_msgs::transformstamped?/) by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use `tf2::transformToEigen` to convert `geometry_msgs::Transform` or `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` to `Eigen::Isometry3d` as shown in [tf2_eigen.h](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/tf2_eigen/html/tf2__eigen_8h.html).

The `Eigen::Isometry3d` is actually a 4x4 matrix.

---

Originally posted by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) with karma: 137 on 2020-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on 2020-11-19**:
Thanks for the reference. So basically `Eigen::Isometry3d.matrix()` returns an `Eigen::Matrix4d`